# Windows in windows desktop still pinned ,don't minimize automatically when I press out of these windows(when press on the desktop window)

Tags: windows, screenshot, windows-10

When I opened any program like chrome or Foxit pdf reader or any window ,why when I press , outside of this windows it does not minimize automatically.it still pinned until I minimize it or close it from the right top of that program or window ,why is that and how to fix it and how to make this property again?[image]

Comment: That is completely normal all modern Windows operating systems (and even before back to or before Windows 7)